# Process item in Ansible loop only if condition is met and restarting SSH service in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ssh, firewall, ansible

I have few simple tasks in Ansible playbook:

```
tasks:

  - name: Reset firewall
    action: shell ufw --force reset

  - name: Manage firewall ports
    ufw: rule=allow port={{ item }} proto=tcp
    with_items:
      - "{{ ssh_port }}"
      - "{{ 80 if myvar == 'yes' else '' }}"
      - "{{ 8080 if myvar == 'no' else '' }}"

  - name: Enable firewall
    ufw: state=enabled
    notify: restart ssh

handlers:

  - name: restart ssh
    service:
      name=sshd
      state=restarted
      enabled=yes
```

and 2 simple questions regarding this tasks:

- is it possible to completely ignore `item` in above loop if condition is not met?
- how to "properly" restart `sshd` service with Ansible after managing ports with `ufw` (since in my case I understandably get an Ansible's connection error when trying to restart `sshd`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to completely ignore item in above loop if condition is not met?

I would just change it to read:

```
- name: Manage firewall ports
  ufw: rule=allow port={{ item }} proto=tcp
  with_items:
    - "{{ ssh_port }}"
    - "{{ 80 if myvar == 'yes' else 8080 }}"
```

...which gets you the same result.  In other situations, you can control which items trigger the action using the `when` qualifier:

```
- debug: msg="using item {{item}}"
  with_items:
  - one
  - two
  - three
  when: "'o' in item"
```

Which results in:

```
TASK: [debug msg="using item {{item}}"] *************************************** 
ok: [localhost] => (item=one) => {
    "item": "one",
    "msg": "using item one"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=two) => {
    "item": "two",
    "msg": "using item two"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=three)
```

> how to "properly" restart sshd service with Ansible after
>      managing ports with ufw (since in my case I understandably get an
>      Ansible's connection error when trying to restart sshd)

Restarting the `sshd` service should not disrupt an existing ssh session.  If it is preventing a subsequent connection from ansible, you could possibly use Ansible's `wait_for` module to delay until ssh was ready to accept connections.

Comment: Thanks! Issue with `items` works now perfectly :) Didn't know that `when` will affect each item in the loop... About restarting SSH service, the thing is that I configure lots of things in SSH, not only that I change the port, so I'm not sure if `wait_for` could help me here... If it can, could you please just briefly explain how to handle it?

Comment: I didn't know that about `when` either until testing it out just now :). Regarding `ssh`, if you are changing the port on which it is listening I'm not sure there is a good solution other than splitting your playbook into two, and running them with different ansible configuration options.

Comment: The thing is that I did split my playbook into 2 - let's say pre-ssh config and post-ssh config with different configuration. I also put firewall tasks in the very end of pre-ssh playbook and restarting of ssh service happens as the very last task in it. This means that ssh and firewall are configured but never applied since ssh service is never restarted properly and then I have difficulties with connecting with any of 2 configurations. In the end I am forced to reboot the machine in order to apply ssh/fw settings :(